# can i use sqlite in appharbor?

Tags: sqlite, appharbor

I use sqlite in my appharbor app. the data file was in "/App_Data". in my dev env,it works good .But when I deployment it in appharbor, there was a error :"SQLite error no such table: Items" . It seemed all the tables was lost.

and I print the connection string ,It was "Data Source=D:\websites\f3\d2b85\15729\0x0001_PublishedWebsites\ToolBox\App_Data\d3ah.db;" ,seemed fine.

so , what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I knew it.
the appharbor build my source code and deployment it.

so,in visual studio, go to solution Explorer and find your sqlite data file.
right click it and then click "properties", and then set Build Action To "Content".
check in source code. Done!

Answer (score 2):

Using SQLite on AppHarbor is not recommended because instance storage is not persisted across deploys. There are more details in the [FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions).